I cannot delete the document via Firebase panel
The free writing quota of 20,000 was reached today. I need to delete some documents, but I cannot delete any documents even though my firebase deletion quota is not yet full. Are write quota and deletion quota related to each other?
I cannot delete via Firebase Panel

According to the documentation, writes and deletes are accounted separately, each with a daily free quota of 20,000.
If you're having problems with the console not working the way you expect or are getting error messages that are not actionable you should reach out to Firebase support directly.  Stack Overflow can't help with that.

I understand, thank you. Normally deletions were working. But for some reason, deleting operations became impossible after the write quota was reached. That's why I wanted to ask if these two might be related.
